# remove duplicate elements through javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom, frontend

how to remove duplicate **li** in **div** using js?

```
<div id="tags">  
  <li id="tag">sport</li>
  <li id="tag">news</li>  
  <li id="tag">sport</li>        
  <li id="tag">sport</li>    
  <li id="tag">cars</li>
</div>
```

must become:

sport

news

cars

Comment: iterate all lis, use something like a set to track texts seen already, remove the li if text is already seen before.

Comment: Remove the id attributes from <li> elements, you can use the class attribute on them. Id's need to be unique.

Comment: Duplicate id and no ul elements, check html please.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do that in following steps:

- Select all the elements  and create `Set` containing all the texts of `<li>`
- Then loop through elements list using `forEach`
- Check if the `Set` doesn't contain the `innerHTML` of current element then remove the element
- If set contains the text then don't remove the element but remove the text from `Set`

**Note:** `id` of element should be unique in the whole document. Two elements can't have same `id`

```js
const tags = [...document.querySelectorAll('#tags > li')];
const texts = new Set(tags.map(x => x.innerHTML));
tags.forEach(tag => {
  if(texts.has(tag.innerHTML)){
    texts.delete(tag.innerHTML);
  }
  else{
    tag.remove()
  }
})
```

```html
<div id="tags">  
  <li>sport</li>
  <li>news</li>  
  <li>sport</li>        
  <li>sport</li>    
  <li>cars</li>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

you can just iterate over the selected node list without much overhead using one loop, like this:

```js
let elements = document.querySelectorAll("li");
textArr = [];
elements.forEach(function(d, i) {
  if(textArr.indexOf(d.innerText) > -1) {
    d.remove();
  }
  else {
    textArr.push(d.innerText);
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="tags">  
  <li id="tag">sport</li>
  <li id="tag">news</li>  
  <li id="tag">sport</li>        
  <li id="tag">sport</li>    
  <li id="tag">cars</li>
</div>
```